# JQUERY and Laravel 5. Send from View to Controller and Modify locale: (code almost completed)

Tags: jquery, laravel

Objective:

From a Dropdown menu I click on an Item and the value gets passed from that View to a controller and the controller on getting it, it modifies its locale (that is, it will provide another language for navigation). If I manually modify the locale, I get a nice translation of my interface, because I have already created the files at Lang Directories etc.

Minor (but blocking) issues that I have:

Since there are many items in the dropdown menu (each corresponding to a language) I have to pinpoint the "onclick" exactly refering to that item. I am not quite sure how the syntax goes there, maybe some .children from the parent, so on clicking on any of the children, its value is sent.

Here is the CODE:

HTML

```
<li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Pick Language<b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="{{URL::route('index')}}" id="french" value="fr">Français</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{URL::route('index')}}" id="english" value="en">English</a></li>  
        <li><a href="{{URL::route('index')}}" id="spanish" value="es">Castellano</a></li>                                
        <li><a href="{{URL::route('index')}}" id="german" value="de">Deutsch</a></li>                                
        <li><a href="{{URL::route('index')}}" id="russian" value="ru">русский</a></li>  
        </ul>
    </li>
```

HERE  IS THE JQUERY:

```
<script>
    $('#english').click(function () {
    var selectedlanguage = $('#english').val();
        $.ajax({
        url: '{!!"languagechooser"!!}>',
        data: { 'locale' : selectedlanguage},
        type: "post",
        cache: false,
        success: function (savingStatus) {

            echo "now in English";
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            $('#lblCommentsNotification').text("Error encountered while saving the comments.");
        }
    });
});


</script>
```

HERE IS THE CONTROLLER

```
public function languagechooser()
{

    echo "recibe \Input::get('locale')";
    \Session::set('locale', \Input::get('locale'));

     return \Redirect::back();


}
```

AND I BELIEVE I STILL HAD TO DO A MOFIFICATION AT THE "FILTERS", BUT LARAVEL 5.0 DOES NOT HAVE THEM; INSTEAD I HAVE READ ABOUT USING MIDDLEWARE, OR THIS FUNCTION WITHIN THE BOOT FUNCTION AT SERVICE PROVIDERS ETC.

```
public function boot(Router $router)
    {
        \Lang::setLocale(\Session::get('Locale'));

        parent::boot($router);
    }
```

I really like and understand the whole process, but I dont master the syntax and the Jquery should be able to receive values from any language clicked.

thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your anchors inside each list item a class of "choose-language". As [Tim Lewis mentioned in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30467112/jquery-and-laravel-5-send-from-view-to-controller-and-modify-locale-code-almo/30468545?noredirect=1#comment49017796_30468545), I'm also not sure whether it is allowed to use the `value` attribute in an anchor or not. I changed it to a data-attribute to make sure this markup is valid.

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Pick Language<b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="{{URL::route('index')}}" class="choose-language" id="french" data-value="fr">Français</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{URL::route('index')}}" class="choose-language" id="english" data-value="en">English</a></li>  
    <li><a href="{{URL::route('index')}}" class="choose-language" id="spanish" data-value="es">Castellano</a></li>                                
    <li><a href="{{URL::route('index')}}" class="choose-language" id="german" data-value="de">Deutsch</a></li>                                
    <li><a href="{{URL::route('index')}}" class="choose-language" id="russian" data-value="ru">русский</a></li>  
    </ul>
</li>
```

With jQuery, you can set the click-handler for that class and get the clicked element with `$(this)`:

```js
$('.choose-language').on('click', function () {
    var selectedlanguage = $(this).data('value');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'languagechooser',
        data: { 'locale' : selectedlanguage},
        type: "post",
        cache: false,
        success: function (savingStatus) {
            console.log(savingStatus);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            $('#lblCommentsNotification').text("Error encountered while saving the comments.");
        }
    });
});
```

I cleaned up your JavaScript a little bit. There is no need to echo out the AJAX URL with Blade. Now for the `data-value` attribute, you can either get its value with `$(this).attr('data-value')` or `$(this).data('value')`.

Hope this answers your question!

Comment: Is an `<a>` tag even allowed to have a `value="..."` attribute? I'm pretty sure it's invalid html. Personally, I would use `data-` attributes, accessed via either `$(this).attr("data-value")` or `$(this).data("value")`. I could be wrong though.

Comment: I think that using custom attributes in HTML5 is valid, so you don't need to append them with `data-`. I'm not sure about the `value`  attribute specifically to be honest, but as far as I know this should be ok as it isn't a reserved attribute for anchors. This is a good point though, I personally prefer using data-attributes as well.

Comment: I changed the HTML and JS to use data-attributes, as it is unclear for now whether the `value` attribute is allowed or not.

Comment: Yes, definitively the corrections are great and the modification of the Jquery very right. I have tried that out and still am not getting the change in the language. This makes me think that it could be then after the controller has received the locale. I am going to give you the answer right and maybe will post under another topic the second part of the issue that I have, which seems to be what happens after the Controller (the Middleware or Service Provider stuff)

Comment: Make sure you load jQuery properly before your script.